# I want to store date in dd-MMM-yyyy (17-MAR-2017) in string say X.

Tags: java, string

in one string say X. Now I want to split this string in another string that is, say y= x.split , such that y[0] = 17, y[1] = MAR y[2] = 2017. How to write prog for this in Java.

Comment: Have you tried x.split? Hava a look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

Try **splitting**:-

```
String s = "17-MAR-2017";
String array[] = s.split("-");
System.out.println(array[0]); //Prints 17. Same way, print others.
```